# How can I pass a preprocessor definition to DLL at library load time

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll

I'm working on an application that links against a DLL which itself contains a data structure whose definition varies depending on a preprocessor definition:

```
struct Example
{
    uint8_t StringA[32];
    #if USE_B
    uint8_t StringB[32];
    #endif
};
```

I need to use both versions of the structure at different times in my application.  It seems, therefore, that I need to load the DLL using `LoadLibrary` with USE_B undefined for part of the execution (this is standard and straightforward), unload it using `FreeLibrary`, and then load it again with USE_B defined to a nonzero value.  I am unsure how to do this, and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Change the code to have two versions of the struct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LoadLibrary/FreeLibrary are run-time concepts and #ifs are compile-time concepts. If you compile a module without the #if defined, it will stay as such no matter how you load or reload it.

Define two classes, one with `StringA` and one inherited using also `StringB`.

Then add a virtual function to the class to make it polymorphric and decide at the *run time* which of the two you want by using `dynamic_cast<>`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile two versions of the DLL with different values of the flag. You can then use them from the binary by loading the version you need dynamically.